# Acessing Remote SQL Server from Visual FoxPro Application

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

Dear StackOverflow readers i would like your kind attention towards my one of the problem:

1. I have a Visual Foxpro application, in which i am accessing a remote SQL Server's Stored Procedure. Everything is working fine when I am installing the SQL Express 2008 in my Client Machine along with the FoxPro Application.
2. But when I am not installing the SQL Server On client Machine along with the visual FroxPro Application then I am getting a error " SQL Connect Error", Cannot Make Connection.
3. Is their any way that i don't have to install the whole SQL Express on client machine and i can only install the required libraries.

Regards
ProgChd

Comment: How are you connecting from your VFP application. Could you post some sample code or steps to reproduce your problem please. By the way this has to be the politest question I have ever seen on SO

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to install SQL Express itself, but at least ensure that you have the ODBC / OleDB providers for SQL Express.  These can use SQL-Server connection which are somewhat common to already be on the machine.

As for your connection string, are you connecting via the fully qualified \server\database hosting information?

Just for grins, you could go through the machine's

```
Control Panel
   Administrative Tools
      Data Sources ODBC
```

and try to manually create an ODBC connection to the SQLExpress server you are trying to do via your VFP application.  If you can't connect through that, then neither will VFP. Take the VFP app out of the equation and just test for the connection.